# How to set env vars on all nodes in a Mesos cluster?

Tags: mesos, dcos

I'm trying to set some env vars on our DCOS/Mesos cluster - what's the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? Set global env vars for all spawned tasks?

Comment: @janisz . Yes, indeed

Comment: The simplest way is to set them in `/etc/environment` or with init of Mesos Agent. If that's not an option you can manage your framework to do it or write [mesos hook module](https://github.com/mesos/modules/blob/master/hook/test_hook_module.cpp) that will inject env vars to the task.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you taking a look at `Consul` and `envconsul` combo.
Use Consul as K/V for storing and managing the variables across the cluster and envconsul to feed them to the apps inside the container. For secrets - add `Vault`.
You have mentioned you were looking for simple solution. I would say it's relatively simple and elegant way to achieve that.